# setting a style using a string value javascript

Tags: javascript, css, function, variables, styles

Hi i want to know if there is a way of setting a style of on object through javascript using a string, i don't know how to explain it very well hopefully my code will

```
function updateElementFromValue(inputval, valueOfStyle)
{
  selectedActiveElement.style.valueOfStyle = inputval.value + "px";
}
```

so i have this function and when i call it, inputval will be an input field and valueOfStyle will be passed as top or left or width etc so it effectively becomes, ignore selectedActiveElement as it is a global object.

```
  selectedActiveElement.style.top = 200 + "px";
```

i figure im not calling it right but i think their is a way of doing this.

Thanks for you help

Comment: selectedActiveElement.style[valueOfStyle] = inputval.value + "px"; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **setProperty** function
`element.style.setProperty(valueOfStyle, inputval.value + "px")`

Also you're able to do sth. like this:
`element.style[valueOfStyle] = inputval.value + "px"`
but I would not recommend it since not every browser supports that.